# Why is not fired DbValidationException when required relationship property is not set?

Tags: entity-framework, validation

My model:

```
public class Post
{
  public int PostId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  public int? BlogId { get; set; }
  public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public partial class PostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
  public PostMap() : base()
  {
    HasKey(c => c.PostId);
    Property(c => c.Content);
    Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();       
    HasRequired(m => m.Blog)
                      .WithMany(t => t.Posts)
                      .HasForeignKey(m => m.BlogId)
                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    ToTable("Post");
  }
}
```

First example:

```
  using (var ctx = new BlogContext())
  {
    try
    {
      Post post = new Post { Content = "Content" };

      ctx.Posts.Add(post);

      ctx.SaveChanges(); // fired DbEntityValidationException "The Name field is required"
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
  }
```

Second example:

```
  using (var ctx = new BlogContext())
  {
    try
    {
      Post post = new Post { Content = "Content", Name = "Name" };

      ctx.Posts.Add(post);

      ctx.SaveChanges(); // fired DbUpdateException "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BlogId', table 'EntityFramework.dbo.Post'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
  }
```

It seems to me as a bug. Why isn´t fired DbEntityValidationException as in first example but DbUpdateException is fired? I need to get DbEntityValidationException. I tried to put [Required] attribute at BlogId property. I get DbEntityValidationException then, but I don´t want to use attributes in Post class. Is it possible to get DbEntityValidationException without using Required attribute above BlogId property?

Comment: `DbEntityValidationException` comes from validation attributes, only.

Comment: But I don´t have any validation attributes in Post class and DbEntityValidationException is fired in first example. So it is strange to me why is not fired in second example as well.

Comment: That's because of the `EntityTypeConfiguration`, which does the same thing as validation attributes.  I should have said EF validation configuration (either through attributes or the fluent syntax)

Comment: And is it possible to configure it somehow to validate relationships as well?

Comment: Navigation properties are not validated to avoid trips to the database.